# Catch resize event and get width of a dhtmlx modal window

Tags: jquery, event-handling, resize, width, dhtmlx

I would like to catch a dhtmlx modal window resize event and get the window's width to add/remove CSS classes on it's content. My goal is to get a bootstrap "responsive" layout inside a dhtmlx modal window.

I never used dhtmlx and I have a hard time understanding their documentation. I wrote the following code, and the important part is the bottom one (the event catcher). Right now, it does nothing, as I suppose I do not have the right syntax.

Would you know how I could intercept a dhtmlx modal window resize and see it's new width, to add/remove css classes? I want to mimic bootstrap media queries, but for the modal window instead of the whole media/web page.

```
var myForm, formData;
var dhxWins, w1;

function doOnLoad() {
    dhxWins = new dhtmlXWindows();
    dhxWins.attachViewportTo("vp");
    w1 = dhxWins.createWindow("w1", 10, 10, 300, 250);
    myForm = w1.attachHTMLString(
        '<div class="container-fluid">' +
          '<div class="form-group col-xs-6">' +
            '<label>label</label>' +
            '<div>' +
              '<input class="form-control" type="text">' +
            '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>'
    );
}
doOnLoad();

w1.attachEvent("onResizeEnd", function(obj) {
    if (obj.width() < 640) {
        $('.form-group').removeClass('col-xs-6');
        $('.form-group').addClass('col-xs-12');
    }
});
```

You can see this [JSFiddle with the above code](https://jsfiddle.net/davidgourde/gdkqaka6/) if you want to try your ideas.

Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had two problems with my code, and finally found the solution for dhtmlx v3.6 (the one I am using).

1. The name of the event was "onResizeFinish"
2. The width was accessible from obj.getDimension()[0]

The code below works perfectly fine to catch the event in the jsfiddle.

```
w1.attachEvent("onResizeFinish", function(obj){
    if (obj.getDimension()[0] < 640){
```